# CloudFormation - Install and configure CloudWatch Agent to EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CloudFormation template that create ec2 instances using LaunchTemplate, but I want to add cloudwatch agent to the instances, but I can't figure what's wrong.

I have 2 configSets, but the cfn-init get stuck in **"02_download_app"** > **"Command run_app"**, this part I run a jar file from /.

Here is the output from `/var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log`, I noticed that after the command run_app the jar get stucked `17:25`, and some time later `17:42` I connect to the instance kill the jar and relaunch and it continues the script successfully, I think the error is some encoding problem, but I don't know where: in the jar? in log4j config file?, etc.

```
2020-06-23 17:25:20,679 main ERROR Console contains an invalid element or attribute "Encoding"
```

[image: cfn-init-cmd.log]

```
    configSets:
      setup:
        - "01_install_java"
        - "02_download_app"
        - "03_setupCfnHup"
        - "04_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
        - "05_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
      updateEnvironment:
        - "04_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
        - "05_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
```

I followed this [template](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/solutions/AmazonCloudWatchAgent/inline/ubuntu.template), here is part of my template and the cfn-init part.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Cloudformation template.

Metadata:
  Stack:
    Value: 2
  VersionDate:
    Value: 30032020
  Identifier:
    Value: template-app-stack
  Input:
    Description: EC2 Instance Types, DB Instance Type and Engine
  Output:
    Description: Outputs ID of all deployed resources

  AWS::CloudFormation::Interface:
    Parameters:
    #....... other omitted .......#
    #....... other omitted .......#
  Resources:
  #....... other omitted .......#
  #backend autoscaling#
    rBackendFleet:
      Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
      Condition: cIsProduction
      Properties:
        AutoScalingGroupName: !Join [ '-', [!Ref pApplicationName, 'asg', !Ref pApplicationEnvironment, 'backend'] ]
        VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref pBackendSubnets
        MinSize: 1
        MaxSize: 10
        MetricsCollection:
          - Granularity: 1Minute
        DesiredCapacity: 1
        HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
        TargetGroupARNs:
          - !Ref rPrivateLoadBalancerTargetGroup
        LaunchTemplate: 
          LaunchTemplateId: !Ref rBackendLaunchTemplate
          Version: !GetAtt rBackendLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
    rBackendLaunchTemplate:
      Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
      Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
          configSets:
            setup:
              - "01_install_java"
              - "02_download_app"
              - "03_setupCfnHup"
              - "04_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
              - "05_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
            updateEnvironment:
              - "04_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
              - "05_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent"
          01_install_java:
            packages:
              apt:
                unzip: []
                openjdk-8-jre-headless: []
          02_download_app:
            files:
              /tmp/backend.zip:
                source: !Sub
                  - >-
                    https://${bucketName}.s3-${region}.amazonaws.com/${objectKey}
                  - bucketName: !Ref pSourceCodeBucketName
                    objectKey: !Ref pBackendArtifactObjectKey
                    region: !Ref AWS::Region
                mode: "000644"
                owner: "root"
                group: "root"
                authentication: rolebased
            commands:
              configure_app:
                command: "sudo unzip backend.zip"
                test: "sudo ls -la"
                cwd: "/tmp"
              run_app:
                command: "sudo java -jar /tmp/app.jar &"
                test: "sudo ps -ef | grep java"
                cwd: "/"
          04_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent:
            files:
              /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json:
                content: !Sub |
                  {
                    "metrics": {
                      "append_dimensions": {
                        "AutoScalingGroupName": "${!aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
                        "ImageId": "${!aws:ImageId}",
                        "InstanceId": "${!aws:InstanceId}",
                        "InstanceType": "${!aws:InstanceType}"
                      },
                      "aggregation_dimensions":
                        [["AutoScalingGroupName"], ["InstanceId", "InstanceType"],[]]
                      ,
                      "metrics_collected": {
                        "mem": {
                          "measurement": [
                            "mem_used_percent"
                          ]
                        },
                        "swap": {
                          "measurement": [
                            "swap_used_percent"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "logs": {
                      "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                          "collect_list": [
                            {
                              "file_path": "/profuturo/app/profuturo-rest-comunicaciones/logs/profuturo-rest-comunicaciones.log",
                              "log_group_name": "/var/log/${pApplicationName}-${pApplicationEnvironment}",
                              "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}",
                              "timestamp_format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f",
                              "multi_line_start_pattern": "{timestamp_format}"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
          05_restart_amazon-cloudwatch-agent:
            commands:
              01_stop_service:
                command: "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a stop"
              02_start_service:
                command: "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json -s"
          03_setupCfnHup:
            files:
              /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
                content: !Sub |
                  [main]
                  stack=${AWS::StackName}
                  region=${AWS::Region}
                  verbose=true
                  interval=1
                mode: "000400"
                owner: "root"
                group: "root"
              /etc/cfn/hooks.d/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-auto-reloader.conf:
                content: !Sub |
                  [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                  triggers=post.update
                  path=Resources.rBackendLaunchTemplate.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init.04_config-amazon-cloudwatch-agent
                  action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource rBackendLaunchTemplate --configsets updateEnvironment --region ${AWS::Region}
                  runas=root
                mode: "000400"
                owner: "root"
                group: "root"
              /lib/systemd/system/cfn-hup.service:
                content: !Sub |
                  [Unit]
                  Description=cfn-hup daemon
                  [Service]
                  Type=simple
                  ExecStart=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup
                  Restart=always
                  [Install]
                  WantedBy=multi-user.target
                mode: "000400"
                owner: "root"
                group: "root"
            commands:
              01enable_cfn_hup:
                command: "systemctl enable cfn-hup.service"
              02start_cfn_hup:
                command: "systemctl start cfn-hup.service"
        AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication: 
          rolebased: 
            type: S3
            buckets: 
              - !Sub ${pSourceCodeBucketName}
            roleName: 
              Ref: pInstanceRole
      Properties: 
        LaunchTemplateName: !Join [ '-', [!Ref pApplicationName, 'lt', !Ref pApplicationEnvironment, 'backend'] ]
        LaunchTemplateData:
          BlockDeviceMappings:
            - Ebs:
                VolumeSize: 10
                VolumeType: gp2
              DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          SecurityGroupIds: 
            - !Ref rBackendSecurityGroup
          EbsOptimized: false
          IamInstanceProfile:
            Arn: !GetAtt rRootInstanceProfile.Arn
          ImageId: !Ref pBackendAMI
          InstanceType: !Ref pBackendInstanceType
          KeyName: !Ref pKeyName
          Monitoring:
            Enabled: true
          UserData: 
            Fn::Base64: !Sub |
              #!/bin/bash -xe
              sudo apt-get update -y
              sudo apt-get install -y python
              sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
              sudo apt-get  install -y python-pip
              wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb -O /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
              dpkg -i /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
              sudo mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin
              sudo python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py --script-dir /opt/aws/bin https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz
              sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource rBackendLaunchTemplate --configsets setup,updateEnvironment --region ${AWS::Region}
              sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? -r "Backend setup done." --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource rBackendLaunchTemplate --region ${AWS::Region}
    ........
    #App Tier Autoscaling#
    #....... other omitted .......#
```

I watched /var/log/cloud-init-output.log, but no clue of the error, says that is some encoding problem but in what step?

```
+ sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack cwp-prod --resource rBackendLaunchTemplate --configsets setup,updateEnvironment --region us-west-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13224: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 13233: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 306: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 309: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 207: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 284: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 290: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 180: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 114: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 130: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
+ sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 -r 'Backend setup done.' --stack cwp-prod --resource rBackendLaunchTemplate --region us-west-2
ValidationError: Stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:496852590701:stack/cwp-prod/80743380-b533-11ea-9ea4-02e40fd26800 is in CREATE_COMPLETE state and cannot be signaled
Cloud-init v. 19.3-41-gc4735dd3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 23 Jun 2020 20:31:35 +0000. Up 23.76 seconds.
2020-06-23 21:31:14,217 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
2020-06-23 21:31:14,223 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2020-06-23 21:31:14,226 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 19.3-41-gc4735dd3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 finished at Tue, 23 Jun 2020 21:31:14 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 3602.81 seconds
```

Comment: Its a common issue, which made me gave up on `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` entirely. Its very hard to find what causes it. Usually when I used that it was due to some tabs in strange places or characters in your init scripts. I haven't found any way to easily pinpoint the issue, except by try and see approach. After that I pretty much gave up with the `Init`.

Comment: Marcin thanks for responde, I resolved the encoding problem but it's not the solution, the cfn-init get stucked in running java -jar ....., then I connect the ec2 instance and kill the java pid and magically the script continues normally, any idea why? some problem with executing commands in background maybe?

Comment: I will add an answer for the second issue, as I can't fit it into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and looking other related questions, I found that the problem was the output of the command `sudo java -jar /tmp/app.jar &`, (*up to here I didn't know if the output was too long or the ascii characters of the banner*), this jar is an spring boot app and by default the logger was in `DEBUG` mode, so I tried to reduce output by setting `INFO`, but it didn't worked, then I realized that maybe the spring boot banner is causing this, so I run the app redirecting the output to /dev/null, after that, the cfn-script ran all the configSets successfully.

`sudo java -jar /tmp/app.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

```
+ sudo /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack cwp-prod --resource rBackendLaunchTemplate --configsets setup --region us-west-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 114: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 891, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 130: ordinal not in range(128)
Logged from file util.py, line 503
```

More info here:

http://www.codeandcompost.com/post/cfn,-utf8-and-two-days-i%E2%80%99ll-never-get-back

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=182478

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring this  `sudo java -jar /tmp/app.jar &`? I think you should kill it in your `Init` after your `test` finishes.

One way to do this could be as follows:

```
run_app:
    command: |
        sudo java -jar /tmp/app.jar &
        PROCESS_ID=$!
    test: "sudo ps -ef | grep java"
    cwd: "/"

run_app_kill:
    command: "sudo kill -9 $PROCESS_ID"
```

I think also `sudo` is not needed in general. Since you are not numbering the steps, have to make sure `run_app_kill` runs after `run_app`.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I would like to say that this answer was helpful but didn't was the root cause, I will add another answer explaining to anyone with similar issue.

Comment: @jhuamanchumo No problem. Most importantly the issue got solved.